# vmware esxi host ha state in election

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, storage, vmware-server, vmware-vcenter

In my Vmware Esxi server 5.1 , 2 host machines which are added as cluster ,there HA state is turned to ELection .I tried Reconfiguring the vsphere for HA it is not working .In cluster it shows issue as

> vcenter server is unable to find a master vsphere HA agent in cluster

Also when i reboot the server,i found some strange logs in task/events as,

> Login in to iscsi target .iscsi initiator could not establish network connection to target

this target is my dell Powervault MD3220i storage servers.

HA option in Cluster edit settings are turned on only.This clustering was working fine but this issue started recently.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a basic approach of this issue : satisfy to the VMware High Availability requirements :

- All hosts must be licensed for vSphere HA ([Licensing by features](http://www.latogalabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/vSphere5-Update-Chart.png)),
- You need at least two hosts in the cluster,
- All hosts VMKernel Management Network need to be configured with static IP addresses,
- There should be at least one management network in common among all hosts and best practice is to have at least two,
- Host certificate checking should be enabled.

Comment: Thank you Julien.These servers were working fine earlier.It is licensed with 2 host connect in cluster,with management Network in static IP and Host certificate enabled.
But whenever I reboot the server I get many errors showing it cannot connect to vmhba37 .Storage server is good for me and iscsi VMswitches are working fine with other clustered servers .But both my cluster server are in election mode